# How to implement a linear congruential generator in Java?

Tags: java, math, random, random-seed, lcg

I am implementing my own PRNG where I should use the linear congruential generator.
One of my methods should generate the next pseudo random number as seen below. The seed is retrieved from the user earlier.

```
MyRandom(long seed) {

Random random = new Random();
random.setSeed(seed);

}
```

This is the method that should generate the next pseudo random number. This is what I tried to write but I don't really know how I could make it work for the next coming numbers. a and b are the chosen constants and m is the chosen prime number.

```
int next(int bits) {

long seed;
seed = (a * seed) + (b % m);
return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));


}
```

Comment: HINT: your `next` method is not using the seed set earlier by the user; it's actually using a seed of zero.  Can you guess why?

Comment: Do I need to initialize the seed in the `next` method in someway? @KevinAnderson

Comment: @Eve00 might be worth reading up on member variables.  these allow state to be retained between function calls